# Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pycharm

I'm creating a scraper and having issues using Selenium to 'click' through the next page. Including my code below. Every time I run my code it simply takes me to the Indeed home page. The error message that shows up when I run my code is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jasminesami/Desktop/WebScraperFiles/ScrapeSelenium.py", line 24, in 
initial_search_button.click()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'click'

My code:

```
import selenium as selenium
```

## In[2]:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

## In[3]:

`#specify driver path DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/jasminesami/Desktop/chromedriver' driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_PATH)`

```
##ask driver to go to indeed
```

driver.get('https://indeed.com')

```
##set initial search
```

initial_search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath
('//*[id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button')

```
initial_search_button.click()
```